# Keep dialog box enclosed within an area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

On http://jqueryui.com/dialog/, they use an iframe to keep the dialog box enclosed within an area on the page. Can this be achieved without using an iframe?

I've tried appending my dialog to a container but that only affects it's position in the DOM, the dialog can still move all over the place.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
$("#terminal[type=launcher]").click(function(){
                $("<div />")
                .dialog({
                    "title" : "root@" + window.location.hostname,
                    "width" : 400,
                    "height" : 300,
                    "modal" : false,
                    "resizable" : true,
                    "close" : function(){ $(this).remove(); },
                    "Cancel" : function(){ $(this).dialog("close"); },
                    appendTo : "#main_section"
                })
                .dialogExtend({
                    "close" : true,
                    "maximize" : true,
                    "minimize" : true,
                    "dblclick" : "collapse",
                    "titlebar" : false
                })
                .draggable({ containment: "parent" });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery Draggable**

> Constrain the movement of each draggable by defining the boundaries of
>   the draggable area. Set the axis option to limit the draggable's path
>   to the x- or y-axis, or use the containment option to specify a **parent
>   DOM element** or a jQuery selector, like 'document.'

`$( "#dialog" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });`

You can contain the dialog in any parent element. Using jQuery UI draggable.

[jQuery UI Draggable Constrain Movement](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with dialogs, only with draggables.

Comment: The dialog is a draggable instance essentially.  Sure it does

Comment: It seems we need to access the draggable directly to do this, I found this somewhere else: `    $("#dialog").dialog().data("dialog").uiDialog.draggable("option","containment","#parent");​ `. I ll give it a try and get back.

Comment: Actually juicy the dialog has a draggable option which requires jQuery UI draggable.  Like I said before the dialog is an instance of jquery ui draggable.

Comment: My bad, for some reason the dialog is not appending to it's parent, your snippet probably works. Thanks for your time!